# Parse error in C code (.h file)

Tags: c, autosar

I am trying to integrate a C code. While building the stack I get parse error from all the files, where I have included this .h file

```
#if( FLS_CANCEL_API == STD_ON )   // Parse error appears here
extern FUNC( void, FLS_CODE ) Fls_Cancel( void );
#endif    /* FLS_CANCEL_API == STD_ON */

#if( FLS_GET_STATUS_API == STD_ON ) // and here
extern FUNC( MemIf_StatusType, FLS_CODE ) Fls_GetStatus( void );
#endif    /* FLS_GET_STATUS_API == STD_ON */
```

### Edit

Macros are defined in another header file

```
#define FLS_CANCEL_API              [!IF "FlsGeneral/FlsCancelApi"!](STD_ON)[!ELSE!](STD_OFF)[!ENDIF!]
```

and

```
#define STD_ON      0x01
```

Comment: have you try to search ? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html

Comment: When you ask about build errors, always include the actual errors, in full, unedited and including possible informational notes in the question body. Please edit your question to include it. And if possible please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well, or at least something which gives more context.

Comment: Where are `FLS_CANCEL_API` and `STD_ON` defined?

Comment: @Stargateur tried that.. That too dint work

Comment: @JohnBode In another header file

Comment: What is this `[!IF ...]` stuff? That's not something a C preprocessor would be able to parse. Are you supposed to run the header file through *another* preprocessor before building? Where have you found this code? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It was generated by some code generator tool. All those options for preprocessing are given. Not written by me. It is generated from config parameters, from the configuration tool..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is code for some drivers written according to the Autosar standard, in the automotive industry. The header file that has:

```
#define FLS_CANCEL_API              [!IF "FlsGeneral/FlsCancelApi"!](STD_ON)[!ELSE!](STD_OFF)[!ENDIF!]
```

is in fact not a header file, it's a template of a header file. A tool takes an Autosar ECU description and those templates to produce actual code. I think your file is the template for `Fls_Cfg.h`, and so the actual `Fls_Cfg.h` would be generated from that template. I'm not entirely sure based on the template but I think it's intended for the *EB tresos Studio* tool.

So you need to use that tool, or if you have no tools, you need to explain in more detail what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with EB tresosStudio. I was trying with DaVinci.. It somehow dint create the required files